# use dynamic Expression<Func<T, bool>>

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i have this code

```
  public class PropertyFilterSpecification : BaseSpecification<Property>
{
    public PropertyFilterSpecification(PropertySearchCriteria sc)

    : base(i => 
    (!sc.VendorId.HasValue || i.VendorId == sc.VendorId)
    &&
    (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sc.Name) || i.Name.Contains(sc.Name))
    &&
    (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sc.Name) || i.Name.Contains(sc.Name))
    )
    {
        AddInclude(b => b.Vendor);
        AddInclude($"{nameof(Order.OrderItems)}.{nameof(OrderItem.OrderedProperty)}");
    }
}
```

now i need to use dynamic Expression>

i need my code to add condition if

```
        : base(i => 
        addif (!sc.VendorId.HasValue , i.VendorId == sc.VendorId)
   .
        .addif (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sc.Name) || i.Name.Contains(sc.Name))
      .`enter code here`addif 
        (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sc.Name) || i.Name.Contains(sc.Name))
        )
```

and please how to build dynamic creitirea

Comment: None of the code in this question will compile.  Please fix your code.

Comment: i think this working with me may be u have misunderstand i need function to add the condition

Comment: We can't help you if you paste code incorrectly.  If you expect any help, you first need to fix the code in the question so it compiles and is comprehensible.  This is not a misunderstanding.

Comment: There is not enough details in your question to help. You need to provide a call that complies that means providing supporting classes if needed such as the base class.  Also it can help if you create a simplified standalone version of the issue in a console project to help troubleshoot the issue, and then you can use that to share safely and easily with the community if needed.

Comment: sir thank for you followups  i need to use dynamic function inesed of using (!sc.VendorId.HasValue || i.VendorId == sc.VendorId)
    &&
    (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sc.Name) || i.Name.Contains(sc.Name))

Comment: the finally result is   public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AndIf<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, bool condition,
                                                             Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
        {
            var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());

            if (condition)
                return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
            else
                return expr1;
        }

Answer (score -1):

```
  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AndIf<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, bool condition,
                                                         Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());

        if (condition)
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
        else
            return expr1;
    }
```